# How to restrict the location of an NSWindow when dragging from a non key state

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindow

I am trying to restrict the movement of an NSWindow to the top of my screen. I have implemented mouse and window event handlers for click and drag. It does work when the window has focus and is key but if I click on another application the click drag on my window I can move it anywhere on the screen and it will flicker between where I am dragging and the top of the screen.

I would really like to capture mouse movement events for the window when it doesn't have focus.

Here is a summary of my project:

```
@interface CustomWindow : NSWindow <NSWindowDelegate>

- (id)init
    [self setDeligate:self];   
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(gainedFocus:) name:NSWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(lostFocus:) name:NSWindowDidResignKeyNotification object:nil];


-(void) gainedFocus:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    hasFocus = true;
    [self setMovableByWindowBackground:NO];
}


-(void) lostFocus:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    hasFocus = false;
    [self setMovableByWindowBackground:YES];
}


- (void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent    // Only called if window has focus (is key)
{
    [self positionWindow]; // Works only if window started drag with  focus (key)
}
- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)event         // Only called if window has focus (is key)
- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)event            // Only called if window has focus (is key) 
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event          // Only called if window has focus (is key)

// Deligate functions
- (void)windowWillMove:(NSNotification *)notification // Is called when not key

- (void)windowDidMove:(NSNotification *)notification  // Is called when not key but only when the movement stops and the window flickers between where i’m dragging and where the code moves it to.
{
    [self positionWindow];
}


I can a function that moves the window to a desired region with:
-(void) positionWindow {
    [self setFrameOrigin: ...];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I also added -(void)positionWindow:(NSPoint)p{ p.y=820; [super positionWIndow:p]; } and that isn't called when dragging from a non focused state.

Comment: I implemented a timer to continuously check the location of the window and move it if dragged from the top region. It doesn't work.